# Migration from Spring Security 2.0 to 3.0: What happens to AbstractProcessingFilter.setServerSideRedirect()?

Tags: spring, spring-security, migration

I have some very old code here that is based on Spring 2.5 and Spring-Security 2.0 - so I am trying to upgrade the code to Spring 3.0 (only the first step).

During this I found the following code:

```
public class FormLoginFilter extends AuthenticationProcessingFilter
 {
  @Override
  protected void onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse res, final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException
   {
    super.onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(req, res, authException);
    if (authException instanceof CredentialsExpiredException)
     {
      setServerSideRedirect(true);
     }
    else
     {
      setServerSideRedirect(false);
     }
   }
 }
```

For Spring Security 3.0 the `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` changed to `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. But during this change the `setServerSideRedirect` method was lost/no longer required, or whatever.

From the [github Spring-Security 2.0 repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/2.0.x/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ui/AbstractProcessingFilter.java) I found that it was implemented/used in the following way:

```
if (failureUrl == null) {
  response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication Failed:" + failed.getMessage());
} else if (serverSideRedirect){
  request.getRequestDispatcher(failureUrl).forward(request, response);
} else {
  sendRedirect(request, response, failureUrl);
}
```

For Spring-Security 3.0 it looks like handling this falls to the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` which uses a `RedirectStrategy` - i.e. the `DefaultRedirectStrategy`. Which only works with `response.sendRedirect`.

So my question is: Has the `setServerSideRedirect` become obsolete - or do I have to migrate the code I found to something else?

Answer (score 0):

The `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` has been changed to `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` in Spring 3.0.

`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is a subclass of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.

Via `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler` an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` strategy could be set.

Then there is the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` which implements `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

`SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` is a subclass of `AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler`.

While `AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy)` allows you to set the RedirectStrategy.

Which is implemented by `DefaultRedirectStrategy`.